# Querying posts by Author OR category

Tags: wordpress

This will give me all the posts that are not the current one open, that are written by the same author, **AND** that meet at least one on the categories on the list.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query([
    'post__not_in' => [$current_id],
    'category__in' => $categories,
    'author' => $author_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
]); ?>
```

But how could I make a query that gives me all the posts that are written by the same author **OR** meet one of the current categories?

How can I make `category__in` and `author` not exclude each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `get_results` and build your own SQL query.

Eg:

```
$querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN $current_id
AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_author = $author_id 
OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_category_ID IN $categories) 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 3
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Obviously this is just an example query but it shows how you could build up your query.

NOTE: I don't currently have access to a WP DB to test field name, so those given above are purelz guesses. So, you'll need to customised the query to meet your real World needs.

You can find more info in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [posts_where](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter and move the OR statement (author or categories) to it.